# Regular Expression: Language of all those strings which do not contain substring 'bb'

Tags: automata

Language={a b}

RegEx of Language of all those strings which do not contain substring ‘bb’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a+ba)*(E+b)
Remember E is epsilon means empty set

Answer (score -1):

if you check this it would work

```
`( a + ab )*`
```

represents strings which do not contain any substring bb.

as it generates strings either lemda or ending on a or ab

Comment: But it'll not accept the string 'bab' which should be acceptable. This expression (a+ba)*(ε+b) covers all strings